Plant-based alternative to isinglass/gelatin for glazing tarts or other desserts
At least in Italy, most dessert recipes that require for a gelatin to make the surface shine ask for "colla di pesce" that should be "isinglass" in English. Despite its name, it is actually produced using pork rind along with bones and cartilage.
For other recipes that use the isinglass (like some type of cheescakes) I can use other kind of starch as thickeners, but here the goal is to make the surface shine.
Are there plant-based alternatives to isinglass suitable for this purpose?

It seems you've got a bit of a translation problem going on here. Looking at the italian wiki page for 'colla di pesce', it seems to say (emphasis mine):

Oggi sul mercato sono presenti principalmente gelatine, impropriamente note come colla di pesce, prodotte prevalentemente utilizzando la cotenna del maiale insieme a ossa e cartilagini anche di origine bovina,


Today, the market mainly features gelatins, improperly known as fish glue, produced mainly using pork rind together with bones and cartilage,

The isinglass you found would be the English term for 'colla di pesce' or 'fish glue' that's properly made from fish. The other kind would be generically known in English as gelatin. Luckily, the Italian Wikipedia page also states:

Alternative vegetali sono rappresentate dall'agar agar e dalla pectina.


Plant-based alternatives are represented by agar agar and pectin.

Googling some recipes for e.g. 'vegan mirror glaze' seems to imply that these materials can indeed be used to make shiny dessert surfaces, or the 'jelly' layer on top of vegan cheesecakes, as the recipes that I checked all use agar agar or pectin. To find out how to best use one of the plant-based alternatives for specific tarts or desserts, I guess your best option is to Google for vegan recipes of those.

In fact agar agar and pectina are the alternative I already use as thickeners, but I don't know if and how I can use them to make the surface shine

@Mark I think you're best off finding some recipes here that use agar agar or pectin specifically. I've updated this a little anyways to also address the 'how to use them' part as best as I can... Since I don't know if you can replace set amounts of colla di pesce with set amounts of agar agar/pectin without also having to add/remove other ingredients, I think your best option here is to find vegan recipes and use the glazes/jelly layers from those... But I'm not the best kitchen princess out there, so someone may have more info on that for you!

A very traditional shiny glaze would be an appricot glaze. Sometimes it's also found under the french name "nappage", for example on Wikipedia. You simply mix apricot jam with water and use that on the tart.
If you are very detail-oriented, you can also make the glaze with pure pectin, you should be able to find recipes for that, depending on your exact requirements and the type of pectin you can access.
Another popular option is sugar syrup, where "sugar" covers not just simple syrup but also things like agave syrup etc.
As you mention starch: starch glazes, especially arrowroot, are also popular for covering tarts, but they aren't as shiny as gelatin or sugar. In the end, you can use water combined with any thickener for a glaze, it's up to you to decide whether the appearance is what you're looking for.
